# Find all real numbers x such that $ |5x-1| ≤ |3x-2|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I'm not entirely sure which proof method to use?

I'm stuck between induction or proof by cases.

--- edit ---

I have gotten a better understanding now, as I am using proof by cases, however it how can I prove that my answer is correct?

Comment: I can't see how induction could be applied. Proof by cases should always work in order to proof such inequalities, but is a little bit annoying...

Comment: If your goal is *understanding* (and not just mastering mechanics), a good starting point would be to *graph* the two curves $y=|5x-1|$ and $y=|3x-2|$, and look for where they cross.

Comment: @BarryCipra I drew some graphs. I really wish the students would do this themselves; by the time they take calculus they would have a feeling for slope, growth, and so on, along with ideas such as betweenness that relate to the original problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squaring both side leads to: $(5x-1)^2-(3x-2)^2\leq 0 \iff (8x-3)(2x+1)\leq 0 \iff x\in [-\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{8}]$

Answer (score 2):

If you square it you get quadratic inequality: $$25x^2-10x+1\leq 9x^2-12x+4$$

Answer (score 2):

draw some pictures......................

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the cases
$$5x-1\geq 0$$ $$3x-2\geq0$$ or
$$5x-1\geq 0$$ and $$3x-2<0$$ or
$$5x-1<0$$ and $$3x-2\geq 0$$ or
$$5x-1<0$$ and $$3x-2<0$$

Comment: Thank you, but how can I prove that this answer is correct?

Comment: More cases are impossible!